# Dynamic vLookUp

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a sales map, and basically, I receive the sales report of the month, and then I want to past it in the whole year report. The problem is that vlookup works under a RC (reference column) to the cell where I am applying the code.

Currently I am replacing the code manually every month, changing the relative columns to +1 and the letters in vlookup to one more.

```vb
'before
Range("Y2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-24],'[VNDFIL " & Data & " GP_(E).xlsx]VENDAS'!R10C1:R91C12,3,0)"
```

```vb
'after
Range("Z2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-25],'[VNDFIL " & Data & " GP_(E).xlsx]VENDAS'!R10C1:R91C12,3,0)"
```

Comment: So what is the problem you want solved?

Comment: You already know about absolute reference because you are using it in the last argument, so what stops you from using `RC1` as the first argument?

Comment: @M.Schalk i want to go from "before" to "after" without finding and replacing manually the code.

Comment: @GSerg `RC[-24]` is a direct reference to the range, that on a monthly basis changes to +1, in this case goes from Y to Z

Comment: @Andre1992 `RC[-24]`, when entered in column `Y`, is a reference to column `A`. `RC[-25]`, when entered in column `Z`, is, again, a reference to column `A`. So what stops you from using `RC1` which is a reference to column `A` regardless of what column it is entered in?

Comment: @GSerg thank you for your help, it solved the problem. Regarding the `Range("Z2")`, do you have any idea on how to make it dynamic? For example: September=Z; October=AA; November=AB, etc...

Comment: There is no answer to that because September would be Z, AL, AX etc, and there is no way to know which one you want. You can only go the other way round (by knowing it's Z you can unambiguously tell it's September).

Comment: @GSerg In this case, September will always and only be Z (not AL, AX, etc)

Comment: That means there can only be one September (and one of each other month), so it would be `Cells(2, 17 + MonthNumber)`.

Comment: @GSerg thank you, you are completely solving my problem. Can you please tell me how to automate the `MonthNumber`? In the beggining of the code I define data `Data = InputBox("[AAAA.MM]", "Período", "2019.")`

Comment: If `Data` is `Date` like it should be, then `Month(Data)`.

Answer (score -1):

The way I implement dynamic VLookup equivalents is by using Index/Match functionality and a Named range for my column of choice (this is the dynamic part)

> Assuming you are using headers, you can implement a dynamic Named Range column as follows:

```
=OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A:$A,0,MATCH("HEADER",'Sheet1'!$1:$1,0)-1)
```

Where 'HEADER' is the header text to search for and $1:$1 indicates the row the headers are contained

Once you have the column you want to take the data from you can use Index or some other functionality to access the data to extract